# Selenium firefox click event removes element from DOM

Tags: firefox, selenium, dom

Consider this setup:

```
<div id="someId">
    <a href="#">Link text</a>
</div>
```

Then I have a Selenium test (using firefox) which executes a link like:

```
IWebElement element = //Get element by XPath or LinkText;
element.Click();
```

After executing this click event, for some reason and **only** in firefox, it removes the entire `<a>` block and I am left with this:

```
<div id="someId">

</div>
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? I have not found anything useful regarding this using google which rather worries me.

**NOTE** : This is NOT only with C# but also Java

Comment: what do you mean with "remove" -> a) you cannot see it anymore when checking with firebug or b) you cannot find it again with selenium? Have you printed the DOM from within selenium code?

Comment: with remove I mean the element is no longer findable, not by selenium nor by firebug.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure there is no script fired on onClick event?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the application, not the automation

Comment: Note that all of this works great in both IE (yes, IE) and Chrome. There is a "prevent default" method for the onClick basically making sure that what event is fired is used by a "data" attribute. i.e. data-fireEvent="functionToCall". I do not really believe anything to be wrong with this though since it does work on Chrome and IE AND it works on firefox while not using Selenium!